# React Native set TextInput default using native voice input

Tags: react-native

I want my textinput default using voice input, just like in ios it can automatically switch to use native voice input to input text, and for android it can automatically switch to use google voice input to input
is it possible to do it by react native or using native code? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a third party library [react-native-voice](https://github.com/wenkesj/react-native-voice)

This library is compaitable with both android and ios. There is a fine introduction on  [medium site](https://medium.com/jeremy-gottfrieds-tech-blog/tutorial-react-native-speech-recognition-d9ae54960565) too.

For Google voice input, This component uses the device’s native recogniton API, which varies for every device. Google Speech API is an external service that you have to pay for, whereas this costs no money.

Comment: tried it and it didn't work !!